# Python: Extracting data inside first set of quotes?

Tags: python, string

Ok, I have a python function that returns this EDIT[ TK open file dialog]:

```
<open file u'C:/WINDOWS/system32/calc.exe', mode 'rb' at 0x0218B390>
```

I am writing a debugger in TK, and I have the debugger open and launch a file. How can I extract just whats inside the first set of quotes? (`'C:/WINDOWS/system32/calc.exe'`) The location inside the quotes will change, so I can't just set the location I want.

Comment: Can you show us the code of the python function?

Comment: Do a search for a quote, then do a search for the next quote.  Store both results as variables.  Slice the string to get what's between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you are printing out the [`FileObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) of an open file. if that is the case: a `FileObject` also has a [`name`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.name) attribute that just returns the path to the file

```
with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') as file:
    print(file)
    print(file.name)
# <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/test.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
# /tmp/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

without regex

```
data = '<open file u\'C:/WINDOWS/system32/calc.exe\', mode \'rb\' at 0x0218B390>'
print data.split('\'')[1]
```

with regex

```
import re

data = '<open file u\'C:/WINDOWS/system32/calc.exe\', mode \'rb\' at 0x0218B390>' 
print re.findall('\'(.*?)\'', data)[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
st = "<open file u'C:/WINDOWS/system32/calc.exe', mode 'rb' at 0x0218B390>".split()[2]
import ast
col2 = ast.literal_eval(st)[0]
print(col2)
C:/WINDOWS/system32/calc.exe
```